# Clarity on the @login_manager.user_loader function for the flask-login

Tags: python, flask

I have been at it with my application for a week now trying to understand the differrence between the following 2 functions when used within flask-login

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
  try:
    return User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
  except:
    return None

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
  try:
     return User.query.get(email)
  except:
     None
```

both of these functions are showing showing the right logs via print in my /login route as shown below

127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2016 05:24:35] "GET /welcome HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2016 05:24:35] "GET /login?next=%2Fwelcome HTTP/1.1" 200 -

but only the latter function actually redirects me to the welcome page

the former function (the first function on top) shows the same on the logs but it doesnt redirect me to the welcome page ,instead it shows me this message

## login_manager.login_message = u"Please log in to access this page."

Can anyone explain to me the difference between these

Comment: Is `email` the primary key of your user table? Probably not. `Model.query.get` does a look up based on primary key. Your first function is most likely querying based on the wrong field.

Comment: (User_id and email are composite keys ) user_id is the primary key ,email is a primary key also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SQLAlchemy, right ?

In the first function, you're doing a SELECT with a WHERE clause that looks like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=XXX`.

In the second function, you're doing a SELECT that is based on the "user" table's primary key. If the primary key column is named p, that looks like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE p=XXX`.

Probably email is not the primary key of your user table, so the first function returns `None`.

Comment: ,yes i am using Flask-SQLAlchemy .....and i think your explanation might validate what i was also thinking.